# Updating a Text widget live (while typing in it) using Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, passwords

**Problem:** I have a Text widget which in my program is a password Text widget, and I would like it to type stars '*' instead of the text that's been writtin into it (updating while typing).

### Code

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

# Changing the title and the size and the bg-color of the window #
root.geometry("400x550")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title("Registration form")
root.configure(bg="#20c74c")

# *THE LOGIN PAGE* - START #
# The username & password text-boxes and the submit button #
username = Text(root, height=2, width=20)
username.pack()
username.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')

password = Text(root, height=2, width=20)
password.pack()
password.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor='center')


# LOGIN FUNCTION #
def login():
    acc = []  # This list will have two elements: first element (index position: 0) -> username. Second element (index position: 1) will be -> password.
    valid = ""
    file_length = 0
    length_reached = 0

    # A for loop to go through the text file row by row. (Each row has the username and the password, they're seperated by a single space).
    with open(r"path", "r") as added_to_file:
        for count in added_to_file:
            file_length += 1

    with open(r"path", "r") as file:
        for row in file:
            length_reached += 1
            acc = row.split(" ")
            if length_reached == file_length:
                pass
            else:
                acc[1] = acc[1][:-1]
            usern = username.get(1.0, END + "-1c")
            passw = password.get(1.0, END + "-1c")
            if passw == acc[0] and usern == acc[1]:
                valid = "Works!"
                print(valid)
                break
            else:
                pass
        if valid == "":
            print("Account doesn't exist.")


# The submit button #
submit = Button(root, activebackground='#2c67c7', activeforeground='#fff', text='Login', command=login)
submit.pack(ipadx=15, ipady=5)
submit.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor='center')

# *THE LOGIN PAGE* - END #

# Navigation system #
register_frame = Frame(root, height=550, width=400, background='#20c74c')

# *THE REGISTERATION PAGE* - START #
# The username & password text-boxes and the submit button #
create_username = Text(register_frame, height=2, width=20)
create_username.pack()
create_username.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor='center')

create_password = Text(register_frame, height=2, width=20)
create_password.pack()
create_password.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')


def register_button():
    with open(r"path", "a") as file:  # Opening the file in 'Append' mode to add the new account to the '.txt' file.
        new_usern = create_username.get(1.0, END + "-1c")
        new_passw = create_password.get(1.0, END + "-1c")
        account = f"\n{new_usern} {new_passw}"
        file.write(account)


# The submit button #
register = Button(register_frame, activebackground='#2c67c7', activeforeground='#fff', text='Confirm',
                  command=register_button)
register.pack(ipadx=15, ipady=5)
register.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor='center')


# *THE REGISTERATION PAGE* - END #


def login_form():
    if register_page['background'] == '#383838':
        register_frame.pack_forget()
        register_page['background'] = '#fff'
        register_page['foreground'] = '#000'
        login_page['background'] = '#383838'
        login_page['foreground'] = '#fff'
    elif login_page['background'] == '#383838':
        pass
    else:
        register_page['background'] = '#fff'
        register_page['foreground'] = '#000'


def reg_form():
    if login_page['background'] == '#383838':
        register_page['background'] = '#383838'
        register_page['foreground'] = '#fff'
        login_page['background'] = '#fff'
        login_page['foreground'] = '#000'
        register_frame.pack()
    elif register_page['background'] == '#383838':
        pass
    else:
        register_page['background'] = '#383838'
        login_page['background'] = '#fff'
        login_page['foreground'] = '#000'
        register_frame.pack()


register_page = Button(root, text='Sign up', command=reg_form, background='#fff', foreground='#000')
register_page.pack(ipadx=0.05, ipady=0.05)
register_page.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.01)

login_page = Button(root, text='Login', background='#383838', foreground='#fff', command=login_form)
login_page.pack(ipadx=0.05, ipady=0.05)
login_page.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.01)

# Font variable #
font_tuple = ("Comic Sans MS", 16)
userpass_font = ("Roboto", 12)

# Changing the font of some widgets #
username.configure(font=userpass_font)
password.configure(font=userpass_font)

# The mainloop #
mainloop()
```

[image: So in this image you can see the program that I've made using Tkinter, and on the screen you can see an example of what I mean]

So if you know a solution to this problem your help would be very useful to me.

- One more thing that I need to mention, I don't know how to use Object Oriented Programing (OOP) yet, so a solution without using it would be great ^-^

Comment: Why don't you use an `Entry`, and pass the `show` argument: `create_password = Entry(register_frame, show="*")`?

Comment: That's because I tried doing it with a Text widget, but if that's actually that easy then I'll use an Entry instead. I'll try that out right now, Thank you!